# Android Change Date Format

Tags: android, date-format

Unparseable date: "20/02/2014"

I have date  "20/02/2014" in String format and want to change it's format to "MMMM dd,yyyy" but it gives error.

Here is the code:

```
  try {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
     Date date = df.parse("20/02/2014"); 
    System.out.println(date); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  

    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hint: Is your date string you want to parse in `MMMM dd,yyyy` format? If not, what should the format string for parsing be?

Comment: Needs two time parsing with two different formatts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code :

> ```
> try {
>           String str = "20/02/2014";
>           SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
>           SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
>
>           System.out.println("Formatted Date : "+sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(str)));       } catch (Exception e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();        }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You're not changing the date format. You are passing date in this format dd/mm/yyyy:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     Date date = df.parse("20/02/2014"); 
    System.out.println(date); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  

    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In order to change the format and have a new Date, you need to use the `format` command

```
SimpleDateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
date = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

your String is in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format

```
 try {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
     String date = formatter.parse("20/02/2014"); 
    Date date2 = df.format(date);
    System.out.println(date); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  

    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
   try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = df.parse("20/02/2014"); 
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); 
    } catch (ParseException e) {  

        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```